# Using JSON parser to object in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to use this [FunctionalJSON-swift](https://github.com/thoughtbot/FunctionalJSON-swift) to parse **JSON** to object but I can't figure out how to use method `performRequest` from [`NetworkClient`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/FunctionalJSON-swift/blob/master/FunctionalJSON/NetworkClient.swift) and obtain my `User` object. This is what I have:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/my_app/user.json")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

performRequest(request, callback: { (data: Result<User>) -> () in
    // how obtain User?
})
```

This is output from url, I think it's all right at this point:

```
{"id":1,"name":"User Name","email":"username@domain.com"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I apologize if this is not the type of answer you seek, as I am going to do this using another library but in a really quick manner thanks to it.

It is actually a library that I wrote based on the ideas on that repo's blog post. You can get it here: [JSONHelper](https://github.com/isair/JSONHelper#json-string-deserialization)

As to the answer: Just get the response as a string and, let's assume that it is stored in a string variable named responseString, deserialize it like this:

```
var user: User?
user <<<< responseString
```

Comment: Thank you, I used your library and it worked perfectly. Do you have any plans for improvements to accept values ​​as `NSDate` and `NSData`?

Comment: I do for NSDate and NSURL. I'll add NSData to my future plans, thanks for the suggestion. ^^